# The ABI of the selected debugger does not match the toolchain ABI

Tags: debugging, qt-creator

When I try to run my project in QtCreator with debug configuration, I get the following error:

[image: "The ABI of the selected debugger does not match the toolchain ABI."]

I don't even know what an ABI is. What settings should I check? What could be wrong?

This is my "Desktop" configuration:

[image: image description]

When I hover it, QtCreator shows the same error in the tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

When I had this problem it was because the debugger did not match the compiler. I suspect here it is because a 64 bit compiler is matched with 32 bit cdb (in the x86 rather than x64 directory).